# adding a regexp filter to block a subdomain and TLD in sendmail

Tags: regular-expression, sendmail

Running Sendmail Version 8.15.2 on Fedora 24 and lots of spam is coming in from (subdomain).(manydomains).us. I'd like to add a filter like what's available in the access file to block and .us TLD's that have a subdomain. For example:
mail.us ---> OK
anything.mail.us ---> REJECT

A regular expression might look like one of these:

```
[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+?\.+[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+?\.(us)$
```

or

```
|(.*\d.*\.us$)
```

Is there a place for this in the sendmail.mc file? I don't think regexps work in the access file. SpamAssassin and RBL's like Spamhaus should start catching these but here's  sample from a false negative:

```
Return-Path: <Forbes.Emergency.Update@waiting.zzelite.us>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.1 (2015-04-28) on
        ourdomain
X-Spam-Level: ***
X-Spam-Status: No, score=3.1 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_00,FROM_WORDY,
        HTML_FONT_LOW_CONTRAST,HTML_MESSAGE,RDNS_NONE,SPF_HELO_PASS,SPF_PASS,
        T_HTML_TAG_BALANCE_CENTER,T_REMOTE_IMAGE,URIBL_BLACK autolearn=no
        autolearn_force=no version=3.4.1
```

Comment: Domain is probably faked, they will probably switch to a new one as soon you block it.

Comment: Right but I want to block all .us top level domains that have a subdomain. That was just 1 example there are many that got through.

Comment: see http://www.hansenonline.net/networking/sendmail-spam.html ; however DROP is far much more interesting than REJECT, but only to be used in some corner cases for obvious reasons

Comment: That page references the access file which does not accept wildcards nor regular expressions and yes we already have enabled:
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')dnl

Comment: I am getting close. Using the K command in sendmail, as noted [here](http://www.xiitec.com/blog/2009/02/25/using-regular-expressions-in-sendmail/), I have my regex as:
`[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+?\.+[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+?\.(us)$`

But that doesn't seem to match. In the example this regex matches using the `sendmail -bt` test:
`^([0-9]+<@(aol|msn)\.com|[0-9][^<]*<@juno\.com|.{10}[^<]+<@aol\.com)\.?>`

Is there a difference between my regex vs the awk/grep style?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Note it seems the indent before the regex and extra line space before LOCAL_CONFIG in the sendmail.mc file is needed. Hat tip to this [XIITEC blog post](http://www.xiitec.com/blog/2009/02/25/using-regular-expressions-in-sendmail/) for some clues as well as the [sendmail cookbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=upCgAjrpJfgC&pg=PT250&lpg=PT250&dq=K%20command%20regex%20%20sendmail%20R$%20&source=bl&ots=7QD825dTpR&sig=i5noQ1uZ07PDmxFoqa2wilhJChU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwkN72utHQAhWHhlQKHaxJD5oQ6AEILDAD#v=onepage&q=K%20command%20regex%20%20sendmail%20R%24%20&f=false).

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
# this will block subdomain.domain.us or subdomain.domain.info but not domain.us or domain.info
Kcheckaddress regex -a@MATCH
   [a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+<@[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+?\.+[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+?\.(us|info)

HMessage-Id: $>CheckMessageId

SCheckMessageId
R< $+ @ $+ >            $@ OK
R$*             $#error $: "553 Header error"

LOCAL_RULESETS
SLocal_check_mail

R$*             $: $>Parse0 $>3 $1
R$+             $: $(checkaddress $1 $)
R@MATCH             $#error $: "553 Your Domain is Blocked for Unsolicited Mail"
```

Here's the proof it works:

```
sendmail -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> Local_check_mail 123@aol.com
Local_check_mail   input: 123 @ aol . com
canonify           input: 123 @ aol . com
Canonify2          input: 123 < @ aol . com >
Canonify2        returns: 123 < @ aol . com . >
canonify         returns: 123 < @ aol . com . >
Parse0             input: 123 < @ aol . com . >
Parse0           returns: 123 < @ aol . com . >
Local_check_mail returns: 123 < @ aol . com . >
> Local_check_mail 123@aol.com.us
Local_check_mail   input: 123 @ aol . com . us
canonify           input: 123 @ aol . com . us
Canonify2          input: 123 < @ aol . com . us >
Canonify2        returns: 123 < @ aol . com . us >
canonify         returns: 123 < @ aol . com . us >
Parse0             input: 123 < @ aol . com . us >
Parse0           returns: 123 < @ aol . com . us >
Local_check_mail returns: $# error $: "553 Your Domain is Blocked for Unsolicited Mail"
```